# Using If-then statements in SAS, multiple variables

Tags: sas

I am using the SAS-University edition. 
I need to create a new ethnicity variable based on existing sub ethnicity.
Is there a way to select 'WHITE all' instead of specifying 'WHITE-RUSSIAN' or 'WHITE-EUROPEAN' and create the new variable.

Here is my code.

```
data agg1;
set agg;
if ethnicity = 'WHITE' then ethnicity1= 'white' ;
if ethnicity = 'WHITE-RUSSIAN' then ethnicity1= 'white' ;
if ethnicity = 'WHITE-EUROPEAN' then ethnicity1= 'white';
.
.
run ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the values of the `ethnicity` variable are always in the format `'<main>-<sub>'`, you can reduce this to one line and zero `if` statements:

```
data agg1;
set add;
ethnicity1=scan(ethnicity,1,'-');
run;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a `:` modifier:

```
if ethnicity eq: 'WHITE' then ethnicity1= 'white' ;
```

Comment: Be aware of one minor issue: it compares to the shortest length of the two arguments, so `"WHI" =: "WHITE"` is true for example.  Probably not an issue here as there are no races with earlier letters of WHITE, but you might have an issue with some of the more complex racial names, especially if this is free text input.